# Failed to create login in ASP.NET using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to make a registration screen with Entity Framework and I don't use a database. Use context of my model

I am following a tutorial on how to do it but using a database and when I create a view from my controller this error appears:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaFMo.png)

Login controller:

```
public class loginController : Controller
{
    private loginContext db = new loginContext();

    // GET: login
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(login lc)
    {
        string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["loginContext"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
        string sqlquery = "select email,password from logins where email=@email and password=@password";

        sqlconn.Open();

        SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", lc.email);
        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", lc.password);

        SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();

        if (sdr.Read())
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(lc.email, true);
            Session["emailid"] = lc.email.ToString();
            return RedirectToAction("Welcome", "Login");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewData["mensage"] = "Username & Password are wrong:";
        }

        sqlconn.Close();
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult welcome()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Model Login:

```
public class login
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please enter your email")]
    [Display(Name ="Enter email:")]
    public string email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Password")]
    [Display(Name = "Enter Password:")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> EntityType `login` has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

It's obviously said that your model has not a key property, change the `login` model like below:

```
public class login
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please enter your email")]
    [Display(Name ="Enter email:")]
    public string email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Password")]
    [Display(Name = "Enter Password:")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

and this error will resolve.
good luck.